# Put 1 footnote's text (mark inside Mdframe) at the bottom in that Mdframe, but below other footnotes' texts + after extra seperation ruler

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

You can see, in the **MWE** below, that the quote carries a title **Serious title of infamous quote**. I would like to have a footnote-mark right next to that title (that is not so difficult you might say).

But, the difficult part is that I would like to have *that footnote*'s text (which should be a `\footfullcite{`...`}`) appear below the other footnotes (but still inside the `mdframe`).

I would also like *that footnote*'s text to appear below another `\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}}` (which should thus seperate the other footnotes at its top; and *that footnote* at its bottom).

*That footnote* will be the bibliographic reference to the source of the quote.

---

**Important remark:** I know it is possible by using `\footnotemark`s and `\footnotetext`s on all the other footnotes, but I would rather not change the codes of all the other footnotes that dramatically (there can be a lot of them, and I don't want to spend time on connecting new `\footnotemark`s to new `\footnotetext`s).

**Just a thought:** I had thought about adding an extra `Mdframed` inside the *quoter*-`Mdframed`, where the inner one would contain the whole quote (but not the title, and *that footnote*) and all of the other footnotes. The inner `Mdframed` should then be customized so that it would not appear with any lay-out to the end-user; at least in a minimal case. But, perhaps there is a much easier and better environment to put inside the *quoter*-`Mdframed`, rather than an extra `Mdframed`?

---

### MWE

*(easiest is perhaps to compile with **pdflatexmk**, in 1 single compilation-run)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{Reference1,
  author =   {{Lipsum guy}},
  title =   {I wrote about Lipsum},
  year =   {2000},
  publisher =   {Lipsum publisher}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, firstinits=true, maxnames=99,bibstyle=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\newcounter{quote}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=12pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
font=\sffamily\large,
leftmargin=-0.5cm,
rightmargin=-0.5cm,
skipabove=35pt,
skipbelow=12pt,
singleextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O) --
    (O) -- cycle;
  \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\sffamily\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
firstextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O) --
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
  \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\sffamily\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O);
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O);
  },
secondextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
  },
]{quoter}

\begin{document}

\begin{quoter}

\begin{flushright}
    \vspace{0.5em}
\bfseries {Serious title of infamous quote}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}}
    \vspace{-1.5em}
\end{flushright}

(...) Lipsum (...)\footfullcite{Reference1} Wouldn't it be great, if all things\footnote{Can you see how the author here is very absolutist?} were slanted; then they would be straight? (...) Lipsum (...).
\end{quoter}

\end{document}
```

### Current output of MWE

[image]

### Example of desired output

Please don't mind the difference in font and font attributes. It's just a mindless photo-edit:

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that came to my mind was using `tnote` from [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable?lang=en), but without any table. And an simple mdframed inside the other as you suggested but not within the extras.

I've tried to mimic your photo-edit hope it's close to what you need.

Notice i'm using Biber backend, just because I already have it pre-configured. But you can use `bibtex` without any issues i guess.

[image: threeparttable tnote inside mdframed]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{threeparttable} %included package
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{Reference1,
  author =   {{Lipsum guy}},
  title =   {I wrote about Lipsum},
  year =   {2000},
  publisher =   {Lipsum publisher}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, firstinits=true, maxnames=99,bibstyle=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex} %notice i'm using Biber backend!
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\nobibliography* % i think you can remove this, can't remember why i added

\newcounter{quote}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=12pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
font=\sffamily\large,
leftmargin=-0.5cm,
rightmargin=-0.5cm,
skipabove=35pt,
footnoteinside=true,
skipbelow=12pt,
singleextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O) --
    (O) -- cycle;
  \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\sffamily\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
firstextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O) --
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
  \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\sffamily\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O);
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O);
  },
secondextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
  },
]{quoter}

\begin{document}

\begin{quoter}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{flushright}
    \vspace{0.5em}
\bfseries {Serious title of infamous quote \tnote{1}}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}}
    \vspace{-1.5em}    
\end{flushright}

     \begin{mdframed}[default,linewidth=0pt]
(...) Lipsum (...)\footfullcite{Reference1} Wouldn't it be great, if all things\footnote{Can you see how the author here is very absolutist?} were slanted; then they would be straight? (...) Lipsum (...).
\end{mdframed}
      \vspace{-1.5em} %you can adjust this if you wish
               \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}}
       \vspace{-0.5em} %you can adjust this if you wish
     \begin{tablenotes}        
     %\item \small \fullcite{Reference1}
     \item[1] \small This is the source of the quote. This book, that publisher, that page...

     \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{quoter}

\end{document}
```